# Jenkins delete files from Workspace in Windows machines

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

we are facing strange scenario while using jenkins. We have created and scheduled jobs in jenkins and assigned few nodes(Windows Machines) to it and executed! After a week all our jobs got deleted automatically. Is this an expected behaviour of jenkins and do we have a solution for it?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an expected behavior. Try to find out what happened and try to reproduce it. If you can reproduce it, then someone might be able to help you with your issue (if it is still an issue then).

Comment: Hi I could see the below details in the log file "workspace cleanup-log":
at hudson.model.WorkspaceCleanupThread.delete(WorkspaceCleanupThread.java:156)
 at hudson.model.WorkspaceCleanupThread.process(WorkspaceCleanupThread.java:146)
 at hudson.model.WorkspaceCleanupThread.execute(WorkspaceCleanupThread.java:72)
 at hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1.run(AsyncPeriodicWork.java:53)


Please let me know how to resolve it, thank you!